# If statement to check an input with a generated phrase

Tags: python, csv, random

I need to find a way to check if my randomly generated answer is the same as the user input and then track the number of rights and wrongs. heres what I have

```
import random

def playerTriviaQuestions():
    fo = open("playerstriviaquestions.csv","r")
    players = fo.readlines()
    rquestions = random.choice(players)
    data = rquestions.split(",")
    rquestions = data[0]
    answer = data[1]
    print(rquestions)
    print("")
    print(answer)
    guess = input("Answer:  ")
    if guess == answer:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")

    fo.close()
```

Comment: what's problem you are facing with this solution ?

Comment: it says wrong regardless of if i had the correct answer. I think its having problems picking up the words

Comment: what data you have and what you are entering? Please give some mode details so we can solve it.

Comment: my data comes from a csv file that would displayed like:

Comment: question,answer type thing. my program here randomly selects a line, then i separated the question so only it should print (even though I have also printed the answer so that i can check my spell in) then I have the user input the answer so we can check if the inputted answer is the same as the actual answer

Comment: the proble seems type of data imputed from `console` and `file`. Please check type of both. Also try @Steve Rossiter solution for `raw_input`.

Comment: Have you tried checking what `guess` and `answer` actually contain?

Comment: yes I have printed the random answer so I can copy it exactly. maybe I can try changing the csv to a txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `raw_input("Answer:  ")` to ensure the type you are comparing the answer to is a string (in python 2).

As far as I can tell everything else in your code should work. You may want to use:

```
if guess.lower().strip() == answer.lower().strip():
```

So that it is not case-sensitive and so that leading and trailing whitespace is removed.

Comment: I actually tried this but an error comes up saying "global name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: what python distribution are you using?

Comment: i am using python 3.2 i believe

Comment: Ah, okay then your code should work. raw_input was renamed input in python3. Can you post the full script? i.e. how you are calling that function. Can we see the .csv? Also see my edit about case-sensitivity which might be the issue.

Comment: yep I will copy paste the csv. I tried spelling the answer with all capitals and everything correct and it still says wrong. did your edit though.

Comment: This Player is the captain of Anaheim Ducks...,Ryan Getzlaf
Perhaps the most famous finish player to ever wear the number 8...,Teemu Selanne
Holds the record for the hardest NHL shot at 108.8 MPH...,Zdeno Chara
What nhl player is known as The Great One,Wayne Gretzky
What nhl player scored the game winning goal in the 2010 olympics gold medal game for team Canada?,Sidney Crosby
Who is the player most known for his incredible "hands" on the Detriot Red Wings?,Pavel Datsyuk

Comment: well that was whats in the csv file… didn't turn out very well on here

Comment: As you are reading a csv file, I would use the [python csv library](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/csv.html).

Comment: how do I use strip on the answer / question?